# IntelliJ show history stopped working

Tags: intellij-idea, svn

I use SVN and when I used to right click on the file and click show history, it showed history of all the commits done by different people but doesn't work anymore and comes up blank. Any way I could have toggled it off somewhere and can turn it back to work? IntelliJ version is 2017.2.0

Answer (score 0):

Project history cannot be disabled - there is probably some error behind this. Check if there are any errors in the [logs](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085)

Alos, clearing the history cache and reloading might help. To clear click the red cross icon in the toolbar of the Repository tab, and then Refresh to reload.